# confusion with cppyy for overloaded methods and error handling

Tags: python, c++, error-handling, overloading, root-framework

I have a `c++` class with several constructors:

```
MyClass(const std::string& configfilename);
MyClass(const MyClass& other);
```

I have python bindings for this class that were generated with [`cppyy`](https://cppyy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) - I don't do this myself, this is all part of the framework I'm using (CERN ROOT, in case you're wondering).

Now, I have a piece of python code that instantiates my class, with a nice `try`-`except` block:

```
try:
  obj = MyClass(args.config)
except ConfigFileNotFoundError:
  print("config file "+args.config+" was not found!")
  exit(0)
```

Now, to test, I'm executing this with a wrong config file. But what I get is roughly this:

```
TypeError: none of the 2 overloaded methods succeeded. Full details:
MyClass(const std::string&) => ConfigFileNotFoundError
MyClass::MyClass(const MyClass&) =>  TypeError
```

So I'm wondering:
Since `cppyy` seems to handle function overloading with a `try`/`except` block, is there any reasonable way to do error handling for such applications?

I'd love to actually get the `ConfigFileNotFoundError` to handle it properly, rather than getting this `TypeError`. Also, what determines the actual error class I get in the end - does it depend on the order in which the overloads appear in the header file?

Any help, suggestions or pointers on where to find more information on this would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Your problem is about `python`, not `c++`. The `try` block lets you test a block of code for errors. The `except` block lets you handle the error. The `else` block lets you execute code when there is no error. The `finally` block lets you execute code, regardless of the result of the try- and except blocks. You should consider other possible exceptions, not only `ConfigFileNotFoundError`.

Comment: Are you sure the `TypeError` is from the last one, and not because no overload succeed. Have you check content of exception (`__context__`, `__cause__`)?

Comment: @Jarod42: You are for sure right that I get the `TypeError` because no overload succeeded.
`__context__` and `__cause__` are both `None`.
I guess my question is mostly how I could get hold of the `ConfigFileNotFoundError` directly instead of letting `cppyy` try all the other signatures and wrapping it in another `TypeError`

Comment: Cannot really further help, I don't know `cppyy`. You should probably ask them more directly.

Comment: @Jarod42 Thanks a lot for your input already, I've decided to create an issue with the `ROOT` team about this: https://github.com/root-project/root/issues/9909

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cppyy doesn't use `try/except` for overload resolution, hence there are also no `__context__` and `__cause__` set. To be more precise: the C++ exception is not an error that occurs during a handler. Rather, as-yet unresolved overloads are prioritized, then tried in order, with no distinction made between a Python failure (e.g. from an argument conversion) or a C++ failure (any exception that was automatically converted into a Python exception). This is a historic artifact predating run-time template instantiation and SFINAE: it allowed for more detailed run-time type matching in pre-instantiated templates.

If all overloads fail (Python or C++), the collected errors are summarized. Python still requires an exception type, however, and if the exception types across the collected types differ, a generic `TypeError` is raised, with a message string made up of all the collected exceptions. This is what happens here: there is `ConfigFileNotFoundError` raised by C++ in one overload and `TypeError` from argument conversion failure in the other.

There's an improvement now in the cppyy repo; to be released with 2.3.0, where in clear cases such as this one (a single overload succeeding in argument match but failing in the callee), you'll get the actual `ConfigFileNotFoundError` instance as long as its class is publicly derived from `std::exception` (but I think it already does, otherwise the error report you posted would have looked quite different).

(Note that CERN's ROOT contains an old fork of cppyy that has quite a bit diverged; you'll have to request them for a separate update there if that fork matters to you.)